# useState not working with render in React app

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am a beginner in React and trying to make a CRUD app. I have this code snipped where useState is being used but when I use the same in a class with render function it gives an error. Can someone explain me why and can convert this code to suit a class with render

```
export default function App(){
    const[userName,setUserName]=useState('');
    const[password,setPassword]=useState('');

    return(
        <div className="CreatePost">
            <label>UserName</label>
            <input type="text" 
            onChange={(e)=>{
                setUserName(e.target.value);
            }}
            />
            <label>Password</label>
            <input type="text" 
            onChange={(e)=>{
                setPassword(e.target.value);
            }}
            />
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: Can you provide us the error? thanks :)

Comment: It looks like you're trying to create [controlled components](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components). Make sure you set the value to be your state, like this `value={userName}`.

Comment: @Kakiz Parsing error: Unexpected token
const[userName,setUserName]=useState('');
        ^

Comment: @Riwen acc. to the document shouldnt it be like `this.state={userName:'initial value'};`

Answer (score 1):

useState() only works in functional component. if you want to modify state in a class based component you have to do it with setState method. Something like this should work

```
export default class App extends React.Component{

    constructor() {
       this.state ={ userName : "" , password: "" }
    }
    
    
    render() {
        return(
            <div className="CreatePost">
                <label>UserName</label>
                <input type="text" 
                onChange={(e)=>{
                    this.setState( {userName : e.target.value} );
                }}
                />
                <label>Password</label>
                <input type="text" 
                onChange={(e)=>{
                    this.setState( {password : e.target.value} );
                }}
                />
            </div>
        );
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use hook inside class component. Convert your existing component into the class based as following:

```js
class App extends React.PureComponent {
  state = {
    userName: '',
    password: '',
  }
  
  handleChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
    });
  }
  
  render () {
    const { userName, password } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="CreatePost">
        <label>UserName</label>
        <input type="text" value={userName} onChange={this.handleChange}/>
        <label>Password</label>
        <input type="text" value={password} onChange={this.handleChange}/>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```